# How to validate decimal places

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

Please let me know good way to validate decimal value, if decimal(4,2) it should accept 2 numeric and 2 decimal places.

```
var value = "44.29";
var dec = value.Split('.');
```

Then finding the length will can be used, I need a better culture specific way. I need a generic solution which can be applied to all decimal field.

Like:

```
validate(int before,int afterdecimal);
var valid  = validate(2,2);
```

Need a generic cleaner solution for this

```
private static bool IsDecimal(string value, int before, int after)
{
    if (value.Contains("."))
    {
        var parts = value.Split('.');

        if (parts[0].Length == before && parts[1].Length == after)
            return true;
    }
    else if(value.Length == before)
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Why do you mention SQL Server?  Is that relevant somehow?  Not sure what you're asking.

Comment: Regular expression? Something like this `^-?[0-9]{1,2}(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$`

Comment: According to decimal(4,2) I want to check, It will be different for other columns.It's not sql server question.

Comment: If `string` inside is culture specific, then you shouldn't deal with it directly. Parse it as `decimal` first (using that culture) and then convert it back to `string` using formatter you are checking against (and neutral culture); then you can apply string logic using `Regex` or whatever disregards initial culture.

Comment: Several ways to get into trouble if you parse strings.  The decimal point is localized, it is a comma in many parts of the world.  So is the thousands separator.  Use Decimal.Try/Parse() instead.  You are then unhappy if value * 100 - Decimal.Truncate(value * 100) is not zero.

Comment: string value = "2009.99";
          if (IsDecimal(value, 4, 4))
          { 
            Console.WriteLine("Valid");
          }

          private static bool IsDecimal(string value, int before, int after)
          {
              var r = new Regex(@"^\d{1," + before + @"}(\.\d{0," + after + @"})$");  how is this
        return r.IsMatch(value);
    }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
[RegularExpression(@"^\d{1,2}(\.\d{0,2})$",ErrorMessage = "Value contains more than 2 decimal places")]
public decimal Value { get; set; }
```

Comment: Probably, you should be more restrictive than `\d+`: `123456789.55` is not `decimal(4,2)`; `\d{1,2}`; `.` looks like a *typo*: `\.` is expected

Answer (score 1):

If you whant just validate, try to use the mod:

```
44.29 % 1 = 0.29
```

Answer (score 0):

From the above answers I was able to do it like this

```
         string value = "2009.99";
         if (IsDecimal(value, 4, 4))
         { 
            Console.WriteLine("Valid");
         }

    private static bool IsDecimal(string value, int before, int after)
    {
        var r = new Regex(@"^\d{1," + before + @"}(\.\d{0," + after + @"})$");
        return r.IsMatch(value);
    }
```